# how to join with IIF function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

Hi I am using MSSQL 2017 and try to figure out how this code works

```
DECLARE @customer TABLE (

    credithold bit,
    id int primary key, 
    deliverycityID int,
    postalcityID int
)
DECLARE @city TABLE (

    cityid int primary key, 
    pop bigint
)
INSERT INTO @city VALUES (1,2666),(2,7889),(3,28917)
INSERT INTO @customer VALUES(1,1,2,1),(0,2,3,2),(1,3,1,3),(0,4,2,3)

SELECT c1.id, pop, IIF(credithold = 0, deliverycityID, postalcityID) as cityid
FROM @customer c1
INNER JOIN @city AS A ON A.cityid = cityid
```

The code gives result like 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxs2G.png)
[image]
But I think it should return like this
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3B19.png)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3B19.png[image]
Any advice? Thank you!

Sorry for the image, I can't post image directly because of not enough reputation.

Comment: what do you want to accomplish?

Comment: I want to understand why that query show results like first picture not 2nd one which I expect to show.

Comment: You are joining "INNER JOIN @city AS A ON A.cityid = cityid " a column to it's self. The only table with cityid  column is city table

Comment: I thought the 2nd cityid is alias of IIF(credithold = 0, deliverycityID, postalcityID) isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right join by doing this just do this:

```
SELECT c1.id, pop, IIF(credithold = 0, deliverycityID, postalcityID) as cityid
FROM @customer c1
INNER JOIN @city AS A ON A.cityid = IIF(credithold = 0, deliverycityID, postalcityID)
```